# avoid re-registration of device pushplugin cordova

Tags: cordova, push-notification

i am trying to develop an android application using cordova which utilizes push notifications using the PushPlugin. i have noticed that the plugin has the onNotificationGCM event callback only after registration. due to this, the device needs to undergo registration each time a notification has to be made. i have multiple pages in my application and i have not incorporated the registration and onNotificationGCM code to all pages, causing the notification to have undefined data when i am on such pages.

i send along a json along with the notification. is there any other way to avoid the registration method and still obtain the required data in the notification ?